# Access Database Size Grows After linking to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010, sql-server-2014

I have an Access database, which is 1.9 GB. I linked that Access database to SQL Server. So far my understanding data flow to SQL server tables if any changes occur in Access database. How about the size of Access DB. Does it keep growing? If so how can I fix it? After linking to SQL Server my access DB size grown

Comment: Do  you have more details on the error?  A complete error message, log file, ...?

Comment: Does Access 2010 is optimized to work with SQL server 2014?

Comment: You want to migrate from Access to SQL Server?  There are many options, like this one : https://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/ms-access-to-sql-database/

Comment: This is not clear.  You have migrated.  So your issue is with linked table?

Comment: did you compress your access database?

Comment: I did Compact and Repair Database, Size decreased and as soon as I refreshed linked table manager - it starts growing.